# How to avoid using 40 variables in a complex MDFIND command

Tags: bash, applescript

I am looking for a better way to do the following.

I am currently reading in up to 40 strings from a text file to build 40 variables for use in this MDFIND command (only first 2 aa_fN vars shown -- where N is a number from 1 to 40).

```
mdfind -onlyin "/Users/username/Documents/AAA/" "(  (kMDItemUserTags == 'Gray*'cdw) && (  (kMDItemDisplayName == '*$KMVAR_aa_f1*'c) || (kMDItemDisplayName == '*$KMVAR_aa_f2*'c)  )  )"
```

Is there a better way to do this without needing to use 40 variables?

Comment: That all depends on what you want to do with 40 strings that you are gathering.  If you know FOR CERTAIN that none of them will be null, you can just create a list with 40 items.  As long as you know which is which, you are done.  You can also create a dummy Record, and use your results to fill in the individual items.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you'd want to approach this with a loop, something like this...

```
repeat with i from 1 to 40
    do shell script "mdfind -onlyin \"/Users/username/Documents/AAA/\" \"(  (kMDItemUserTags == 'Gray*'cdw) && (  kMDItemDisplayName == '*$KMVAR_aa_f" & i & "*'c )  )\""
    -- do something with rslts
end repeat
```

Note: I did not test your original code for mistakes